# Cannot make bootstrap work with Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I am working with a `webpack-dev-server` and I am trying to include bootstrap.

I have this project structure:

```
── css
│   └── bootstrap.min.css
│── js
|   └── bootstrap.min.js
├── dist
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── server.js
├── src
│   ├── actions.js
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── components
│   ├── constants
│   ├── index.js
│   └── reducers.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

This is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Whenever I run the server, I get an error of the type:

```
Cannot GET /css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  }
};
```

Everything else works fine, the problem is just bootstrap. I tried a lot of different variations on the configurations, but I can't get it to work.

I also tried requiring it directly from javascript on `index.js`:

```
import '../css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./css/bootstrap.min.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot in /home/lhahn/dev/javascript/sha/css
 @ ./~/css-loader!./css/bootstrap.min.css 6:3278-3330 6:3348-3400
```

### Edit

From what I realised, webpack is trying to find a font file inside my project, when trying to import Bootstrap.min.css.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that webpack cannot load font files.

1. Add `file-loader` via npm to your project, and save it as devDependencies.

   ```
   npm install file-loader --save-dev
   ```
2. And modify the module loaders configuration in your webpack.config.js

   ```
   {
     test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
     loader: 'file-loader',
   }
   ```

Try installing bootstrap through **npm**, remember also jquery, its dependency

Comment: I installed with, `npm install file-loader --save-dev`, but the error still persists

Comment: yes, I updated the question. I also get five of this errors, saying that it was not possible to find the fonts on my root directory.

Comment: Is bootstrap installed via npm?

Comment: Try installing it through npm, remember also jquery, its dependency

Comment: Which one worked exactly? Can you upload the entire code somewhere?

Comment: This was helpful, but created a bunch of junk files. I recommend using 
      `{
        test: [/\.woff?$/, /\.woff2?$/, /\.ttf?$/, /\.eot?$/, /\.svg?$/],
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }`

Answer (score 4):

This what I have in order for `Bootstrap` to work with `Webpack`:

```
{test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
{test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
{test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
{test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
```

and

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Also, if you are using `Bootstrap` locally, you need to have `fonts` folder, containing `Bootstrap` fonts at the same level as `css` folder.  It's best to use `npm` to avoid all this trouble.

Comment: sadly now I get this error: `ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'url' in /home/lhahn/dev/javascript/sha/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:4622-4676
`

Comment: sure, cause you need to install url loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-loader

Comment: For us beginners, *where* do these things go? The font loading lines are for webpack.config.js. The import ?

Answer (score 1):

compared to @krl answer. this is what I put under modules `rules` in
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js

after having `$ npm install style-loader css-loader url-loader --save-dev`

```
{test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'file-loader'},
{test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, use: 'url-loader?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
{test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
{test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a number of different files/fonts/images that needs specific loaders. Check if all loaders in following list are present, if not npm install them as devDependencies and add in webpack.config.js as :

```
loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "html"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.txt$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
            }, {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|wav|mp3)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
```

And in your main/entry file i.e. index.js/app.js include bootstrap css as :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

This configuration is only for using bootstrap css with ReactJS.